# Greater than (>) not working in mysql query

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-5.1, sequelpro

I'm trying to run a query on my WordPress database to get a list of all posts and some other data from a certain month. I'm running into an issue with `post_date`, where looking for posts before a certain date works fine, but looking for posts after a certain date returns 0 results.

This example returns 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_date` > '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
```

However this returns a ton of results:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_date` < '2014-01-01 00:00:00';
```

There are posts published after 2014-01-01, so that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version are you using? This problem is not reproducable with a `datetime` column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12566f/3

Comment: I'm using version 5.1, through Sequel Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting that field as a date if all you want to evaluate is the date:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE CAST(post_date AS DATE) > '2014-01-01'
```

Comment: Good thought. Still returns 0 results.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Does your SQL GUI require you to specify the database name? You may need dbname.wp_posts - I know that is the default for MySQL Workbench at least.

Answer (score 0):

Check your column datatype in your table where date column exist

Comment: `post_date` is of type datetime

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think it will be useful

SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_date`  '< 2014-01-01 00:00:00';